# Persistent Arch Linux USB installation only (automatically) bootable on USB 2.0 ports

Tags: grub, kernel-modules, live-usb, initramfs, firmware

**Short form:**

Booting Arch Linux from USB Device is possible without problems using a USB 2.0 port. Some custom persistent Windows Installation from another identical USB Device also bootable without any problems, regardless of using USB 2.0 or 3.0.

Booting Arch Linux Installation using USB 3.0 only possible by being thrown into initramfs, manually unplugging and replugging the Device, manually typing the mount command for the specific UUID, and manually typing Exit.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Gtp.jpg

---

**Long form:**

I'm using NVMe -> USB 3.0 converter enclosures to create some really snappy persistent USB mountable OS installations and so far had great success with some persistent Windows installation tool. I tried to achieve the same thing with an Arch Linux (Manjaro) installation.

When using a USB 2.0 port, GRUB loads, automatically boots into my installation which itself starts up without any problems. Doing the same thing on a USB 3.0 port however, initramfs can not find the UUID defined in `grub.cfg` anymore.

```
ERROR: device `UUID=b6c7[...]` not found. Skipping fsck.
mount: /new_root can't find UUID=b6c7[...].
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell.
```

The block devices are missing entirely in `/dev` (should appear as `/dev/sdaX` and `/dev/disk/by-uuid/b6c7[...]`).

When I un- and replug the USB device itself (while **still** being in the initramfs shell), suddenly everything's mounted properly (e.g. the device and all partitions appear under `/dev`, `$ blkid` is now showing every correctly) and I can boot without any problems by manually doing

```
mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/[...] new_root  # OR: mount /dev/sda2 new_root
exit
```

This is the device I'm using (while being plugged into the USB 3.0 port)

```
$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
    |__ [...]
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
$ lsusb
[...]
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 152d:0583 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS583Gen 2 to PCIe Gen3x2 Bridge
$ lsblk
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda     8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─sda1
│       8:1    0   300M  0 part /mnt/boot/efi
└─sda2
        8:2    0 232,6G  0 part /mnt
[...]
$ lsblk -o PATH,PTTYPE,PARTTYPE,FSTYPE,PARTTYPENAME,UUID
PATH           PTTYPE PARTTYPE                             FSTYPE PARTTYPENAME                 UUID
/dev/sda       gpt                                                                             
/dev/sda1      gpt    c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b vfat   EFI System                   427C-611E
/dev/sda2      gpt    0fc63daf-8483-4772-8e79-3d69d8477de4 ext4   Linux filesystem             b6c724c4-8c0f-443c-b596-e909ef18da76
[...]
```

What I tried so far:

- Installing `linux-firmware-qlogic` and `upd72020x-fw` to reduce errors during `mkinitcpio`
- Forcing load of modules `uas usb_storage xhci_pci xhci_hcd` in `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`
- Rearranging HOOKS in `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` as described in https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Install_Arch_Linux_on_a_removable_medium (`block` and `keyboard` Hooks *before* the `autodetect` hook)
- Booting with "fallback" initramfs (which should not have `autodetect` enabled and every module baked in, right?)

All without success.

Directly after being thrown into initramfs, atleast some of the modules seem to have been loaded

```
$ lsmod   
usbhid
xhci_pci
xhci_pci_renesas
uas
usb_storage
[...]
```

`mkinitcpio`:

```
$ cat /etc/mkinitcpio.conf
MODULES="uas usb_storage xhci_pci xhci_hcd"
[...]
HOOKS="base udev modconf block keyboard autodetect keymap consolefont plymouth filesystems fsck"
[...]
$ mkinitcpio -P
==> Building image from preset: /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux61.preset: 'default'
  -> -k /boot/vmlinuz-6.1-x86_64 -c /etc/mkinitcpio.conf -g /boot/initramfs-6.1-x86_64.img --microcode /boot/amd-ucode.img --microcode /boot/intel-ucode.img
==> Starting build: '6.1.22-1-MANJARO'
  -> Running build hook: [base]
  -> Running build hook: [udev]
  -> Running build hook: [modconf]
  -> Running build hook: [block]
==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: 'wd719x'
==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: 'aic94xx'
  -> Running build hook: [keyboard]
  -> Running build hook: [autodetect]
  -> Running build hook: [keymap]
  -> Running build hook: [consolefont]
==> WARNING: consolefont: no font found in configuration
  -> Running build hook: [plymouth]
  -> Running build hook: [filesystems]
  -> Running build hook: [fsck]
==> Generating module dependencies
==> Creating gzip-compressed initcpio image: '/boot/initramfs-6.1-x86_64.img'
==> Image generation successful
==> Building image from preset: /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux61.preset: 'fallback'
  -> -k /boot/vmlinuz-6.1-x86_64 -c /etc/mkinitcpio.conf -g /boot/initramfs-6.1-x86_64-fallback.img -S autodetect --microcode /boot/amd-ucode.img --microcode /boot/intel-ucode.img
==> Starting build: '6.1.22-1-MANJARO'
  -> Running build hook: [base]
  -> Running build hook: [udev]
  -> Running build hook: [modconf]
  -> Running build hook: [block]
==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: 'wd719x'
==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: 'aic94xx'
  -> Running build hook: [keyboard]
  -> Running build hook: [keymap]
  -> Running build hook: [consolefont]
==> WARNING: consolefont: no font found in configuration
  -> Running build hook: [plymouth]
  -> Running build hook: [filesystems]
  -> Running build hook: [fsck]
==> Generating module dependencies
==> Creating gzip-compressed initcpio image: '/boot/initramfs-6.1-x86_64-fallback.img'
==> Image generation successful
==> Building image from preset: /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux62.preset: 'default'
  -> -k /boot/vmlinuz-6.2-x86_64 -c /etc/mkinitcpio.conf -g /boot/initramfs-6.2-x86_64.img --microcode /boot/amd-ucode.img --microcode /boot/intel-ucode.img
==> Starting build: '6.2.9-1-MANJARO'
  -> Running build hook: [base]
  -> Running build hook: [udev]
  -> Running build hook: [modconf]
  -> Running build hook: [block]
==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: 'wd719x'
==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: 'aic94xx'
  -> Running build hook: [keyboard]
  -> Running build hook: [autodetect]
  -> Running build hook: [keymap]
  -> Running build hook: [consolefont]
==> WARNING: consolefont: no font found in configuration
  -> Running build hook: [plymouth]
  -> Running build hook: [filesystems]
  -> Running build hook: [fsck]
==> Generating module dependencies
==> Creating gzip-compressed initcpio image: '/boot/initramfs-6.2-x86_64.img'
==> Image generation successful
==> Building image from preset: /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux62.preset: 'fallback'
  -> -k /boot/vmlinuz-6.2-x86_64 -c /etc/mkinitcpio.conf -g /boot/initramfs-6.2-x86_64-fallback.img -S autodetect --microcode /boot/amd-ucode.img --microcode /boot/intel-ucode.img
==> Starting build: '6.2.9-1-MANJARO'
  -> Running build hook: [base]
  -> Running build hook: [udev]
  -> Running build hook: [modconf]
  -> Running build hook: [block]
==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: 'wd719x'
==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: 'aic94xx'
  -> Running build hook: [keyboard]
  -> Running build hook: [keymap]
  -> Running build hook: [consolefont]
==> WARNING: consolefont: no font found in configuration
  -> Running build hook: [plymouth]
  -> Running build hook: [filesystems]
  -> Running build hook: [fsck]
==> Generating module dependencies
==> Creating gzip-compressed initcpio image: '/boot/initramfs-6.2-x86_64-fallback.img'
==> Image generation successful
```

Pictures of some further initramfs investigations: https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Gtp.jpg

Comment: I honestly thought I made it pretty clear. The problem is: Booting from this USB Device is only possible (atleast on USB 3.0 Ports) by being thrown into initramfs, manually unplugging and replugging the Device, manually typing the mount command for the specific UUID, and manually typing Exit. Instead of just Booting and letting grub and initramfs doing its things automagically.

Comment: OK. I added this as TL/DR in the beginning of the question, let's delete the comments to leave space for Those In The Know :-)